# Weighting an hypothetical biased dataset

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, weights

The topic is somewhat generic but I will try to specify it as much as possible.

Theoretically, we have a dataset that being a survey could be biased (geographically, gender ...) in this case are about 100k respondents.

This dataset is a sample of people with their characteristics and a response variable of a survey that measures the propensity to buy bicycles "bike_buyer".

#### Question

Because this dataset is used to train a ML problem. Prior to training the model:

**would it be correct to weight the variables in the dataset to correct their distribution towards a correct theoretical distribution?**

I have not seen publications on this type of methodology, I wonder, if it is correct to do so.

I understand that this question is open, since I cannot specify certain issues such as, what is the way of weighting, how are the weights obtained?

So it can be answered from first in a generic way with yes/no and why. And comment or add some methodology or article on the subject, to demonstrate good practice.

Comment: For a start, (re)weighting a sample to match population totals/means is known as "raking" in the survey literature, or "iterative proportional fitting".

Comment: Note that while weighting can reduce any bias in estimates/predictions owing to the sampling procedure, it increases their variance. If your predictors control for sampling bias, it may well be counter-productive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the webpage "[Raking Survey Data (a.k.a. Sample Balancing)](https://www.abtassociates.com/raking-survey-data-aka-sample-balancing)" by Abt Associates:

> A survey sample may cover segments of the target population in
> proportions that do not match the proportions of those segments in the
> population itself.  The differences may arise, for example, from
> sampling fluctuations, from nonresponse, or because the sample design
> was not able to cover the entire target population.  In such
> situations one can often improve the relation between the sample and
> the population by adjusting the sampling weights of the cases in the
> sample so that the marginal totals of the adjusted weights on
> specified characteristics agree with the corresponding totals for the
> population.  This operation is known as raking or sample-balancing,
> and the population totals are usually referred to as control totals.
>
> Raking assigns a weight value to each survey respondent such that the
> weighted distribution of the sample is in very close agreement with
> two or more marginal control variables.  For example, in household
> surveys the control variables are typically sample design and
> socio-demographic variables.  Raking is an iterative process that uses
> the sample design weight as the starting weight and terminates when
> the convergence criterion is achieved.  The resulting final weight may
> however exhibit considerable variability, with some sampling units
> having extremely low or high weights relative to most of the other
> sampling units.  This leads to inflated sampling variances of the
> survey estimates.  To combat this problem we enhanced the previously
> released IHB Raking macro by adding two weight trimming options that
> are implemented during the actual iterative process, allowing one to
> achieve convergence while controlling the highest and lowest weight
> values.

[Stackoverflow code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743988/stratified-sampling-with-priors-in-python)

Comment: Please ensure you clearly distinguish what you've written yourself from what you've copied from your source (for which you ought to provide a readable reference, not just a bare link). If your answer then consists entirely of a quote you might as well delete it & link to the source in a comment; or, better, add your own commentary and explanation of how it helps answer the question. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: It was almost done, I think now is the desired format with the quote and source link.